# JavaScript array.length remains 0 after elements been pushed in

Tags: javascript, brackets

Im writing a brackets validation function, and seems like under some conditions the `tmpStack.length` remains `0` even after some elements been pushed in.
For normal input like `"[(1+2)]"`or `"[(1+2]"` the function works, but for input such as `"[12"` it doesnt, for the reason that `tmpStack.length` remains `0`. Another issue that bothers me, if the input is a single bracket like `[` the function returns `true` although it should fail in the initial validation.

```
function validator(str){
  var flag=true;
  var tmpStack=[];
  var sliced = str.split("");
  if (str.length<1 && 
        ((str!="(") || (str!=")") || (str!="[") || 
         (str!="]") || (str!="{") || (str!="}")))
    return flag;

  else {
        for(var i =0;i<=str.length;i++){
            if((sliced[i]=="[") || (sliced[i]=="{") || (sliced[i]=="("))
                tmpStack.push(sliced[i]);
            else {
                if((sliced[i]=="]" && tmpStack.pop()!="[") || (sliced[i]=="}" && tmpStack.pop()!="{" ) || (sliced[i]==")" && tmpStack.pop()!="("))
                {
                    console.log("dis-match found for: "+(sliced[i]));
                    flag=false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(tmpStack.length % 2)
    return flag;
    else
    return !flag;
}
var tstStr="[+1";
console.log(validator(tstStr));
```

Comment: Changes for me -> **http://jsfiddle.net/upzt7a8c/**

Comment: Your code drives me crazy... A validator should always return `false` if it encounters problems: `if( myValidator(str) ){ /*all fine*/ }`, you're starting instead with a `true` flag. Let me guess, so you want to run your validator trough a string and match handwritten JSON-alike brackets errors/mismatches? What if a string contains a literal `}` or any other bracket? What are trying to parse?

Comment: It should return true or false, according to the input. The input is a simple string with brackets, curly braces, parenthesis.

Comment: I dont understand `if (str.length<1 && ((str!="(") || (str!=")") || (str!="[") || (str!="]") || (str!="{") || (str!="}")))` if the length is <1 its the empty string so there is no reason to check the value

Comment: Youre right, it should be `str.length<=1`.

Comment: @undroid what are you talking about? If string length `<=` means also if it's `0` than you do an `&& str !=` .... Again what are you trying to build? Are you strings complicated JSON literals? Simple code string with non-deep nested brackets or what?

Comment: Roko I didnt understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you catch an error you need to return from the function, I think:

`return false;`

instead of

`flag=false;
 break;`

also I didn't undertand that:

`if(tmpStack.length % 2)
    return flag;
    else
    return !flag;`

it seems if anything left in array - if should return false:

`return tmpStack.length ? false : true;`

or just

`return !tmpStack.length`

http://jsfiddle.net/m68j0926/

**Updated**

Refactored solution:

```js
function validator(str){
    var tmpStack = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i].match(/\[|\{|\(/)) {
            tmpStack.push(str[i]);
        } else if (
                (str[i]=="]" && tmpStack.pop()!="[") || 
                (str[i]=="}" && tmpStack.pop()!="{" ) || 
                (str[i]==")" && tmpStack.pop()!="(")
        ) {
            console.log("dis-match found for: " + (str[i]));
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    return !tmpStack.length;
}
var tstStr="[+]()1";
console.log(validator(tstStr));
```

Comment: Good point regarding the return method if anything still remains inside. But the main point here that the length of the `tmpStack` is always 0.

Comment: It seems not.. only those changes that I described

Comment: Is there any way to improve the logic of the function? Besides what you've described.